# Folders are missing after publishing web-application in visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, publish

When i publish my web-application some folders are missing like Images,Javascript,Css

I have tried publishing it by FTP and FileSystem profile nothing works

Comment: what kind of application you are trying to publish? generally, you could choose a folder option or iis web deploy.

Answer (score 1):

What I did that worked for me was first I "exclude from project" all the files that were missing from the project. Then I Right Clicked/Add/Existing Item to all the files that I originally "exclude from project". After that I clicked the the files that I added and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always". You don't have to do all the files that you are missing at once. Try it for a few files to see if this solution works

Answer (score 0):

Usually that happens when those files are not included in the solution.

Files can be added to the project in several ways:

- Right click the project or contained folder and choose Add. | Existing Item... .
- Use Show All Files . Click on files or folders you would like to add to the project and choose Include In Project .
- Drag and drop files and folders from Windows Explorer.